# Using PyParallel in Windows XP

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-xp, parallel-port

I have successfully implemented the PyParallel module in both Linux and Mac OSX as part of a large application to interface with a sensor I am developing.... I am now attempting to use this application on an instance of Windows XP.  I have found several references (including right from the PySerial/PyParallel group) that:

> The windows version needs a compiled extension and the giveio.sys driver for Windows NT/2k/XP. It uses ctypes to access functions in a prebuilt DLL.

However, I don't know what "a compiled extension" requirement is.  And, I can't seem to get givio.sys to work.  I obtained giveio.sys [here](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eblock/pages/pictools/giveio.html) and followed the recommendations, but LoadDrv.exe fails to "start" the service (it does "install", however).

I cannot find specific examples online of getting PyParallel working on Windows XP.  Since PyParallel is "thoroughly" integrated into the application and is working on both Linux and Mac OSX, I'd prefer not to use a different module -- especially since PyParallel is great to not require root/administrator privileges to utilize.

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble with giveio.sys and LoadDrv.exe as well.

There is a handy installer that does it all automatically:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyserial/files/pyparallel/giveio/

Comment: I was never able to get giveio.sys to work and "abandoned" using the parallel port as a normal user in favor of using a different solution via USB.  I will try your solution, though... and upvote/accept if it works.  Thanks!